# infinality fonts and Windows fonts emulation

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I want to emulate Windows 7 fonts on my Ubuntu 13.10 system. I installed [infinality](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html) and tried a couple of themes via  `infctl.sh` (`Win7` and `OSX2` ones). Alas, none of them was fully suitable: `OSX2` theme needs to be darker and `Win7` theme needs to be thicker.

I tried to modify the filter matrix via `infinality-settings.sh`. It writes the proper (modified) values to the environment variables, but nothing happens  to my rendered fonts. I restarted my machine several times, but it does not help.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to modify my filter settings?

P.S. My antialiasing settings are [here.](http://i.zlowiki.ru/140318_a2bb873d.png)

[image: A comparison between real Windows fonts and pre-defined themes of <code>infinality</code>]

Comment: The screenshot is too small to actually differentiate between the renderings...

Comment: It's automatically resized, take its full version: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3HjS0.png

Comment: I've modified the image above so that you can now click on it to get a full sized version in a separate tab.

Comment: Heh, here was the answer: the freetype was not patched.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22540156/2726900